# Are strange metals described by a quantum critical theory?

Tags: condensed-matter

Are strange metals -- metallic states that are not describable by the traditional theory of metals (Landau's [Fermi liquid theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_liquid_theory)) -- described by a quantum critical theory?

Comment: I'm not a great fan of this question because it doesn't have an answer yet because we don't know. This kind of question simply invites controversy and grandstanding. If it said "what experimental aspects of strange metals are explained by quantum criticality?" Then there can be a sensible discussion.

Comment: A link or basic explanation of "strange metal" would be useful to those of us who read the title and said *"Huh?!?"*.

Comment: -1. Please edit the question for clarity and detail.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of work on quantum criticality and its CFT equivalence with AdS.  Take a look at:

String Theory, Quantum Phase Transitions and the Emergent Fermi-Liquid
Authors: Mihailo Cubrovic, Jan Zaanen, Koenraad Schalm

http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1993

Another paper which is less conformal field related is

Quantum Criticality in Heavy Fermion Metals
Authors: Philipp Gegenwart, Qimiao Si, Frank Steglich
(Submitted on 13 Dec 2007 (v1), last revised 31 Jan 2008 (this version, v2))

http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2045